# Is $a$ in relation to $b$ if and only if $a+b$ congruent to $0$ (mod) transitive.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove that this is an equivalence relation, and I have proven reflexivity and symmetry true. I believe that I have proven that transitivity fails, but I am not sure.
so since I want to show that if $a+b$ is congruent to $0 (\text{mod }2)$ and $b+c$ is congruent to $0$ $(\text{mod }2)$ then $a+c$ is congruent to $0$ $(\text{mod }2)$. Thus I want to see if $2|a+c$. I know that $2|a+b$ and $2|b+c$ so I can write that $a+b=2m$ and $b+c=2p$ for some integers $m$ and $p$. if I let $b = 2m-a$ and plug that into the equation $b+c =2p$ I get that $2m-a+c=2p$ which results in $-a+c=2(p-m)$. So here I would say transitivity fails, however, if I think about it logically, transitivity should not fail.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a+b=2m$. and $b+c=2n$.

Then $a+c=a+b+b+c-2b=2m+2n-2b=2(m+n-b)$

Answer (score 1):

So you have, by definition, that $a \equiv b$ if $2 \mid a + b$ and you want to check whether this relation is transitive. That is, you want to determine if: $a \equiv b$ and $b\equiv c$ implies $a \equiv c$.

Say $a \equiv b$ and $b\equiv c$. Then $2 \mid a+b$ and $2 \mid b+c$. That means that $a+b$ is even so either $a$ and $b$ are both odd or both even (since odd plus even gives odd). That is $a$ and $b$ have the same parity. For the same reason $b$ and $c$ have the same parity. So $a$ and $c$ have the same parity. So ...

Answer (score 0):

***Hint:***

If $a + b = 2p$ then what about $a +  (- b) = a + b - 2b$ ?? Use this two prove transitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Finally you got $-a+c=2(p-m)$ and you need to have $a+c$ is divisible by 2. From $-a+c=2(p-m)$, get c and plug in $a+c$. you will have $a+c=2(p-m+a)$,i.e., divisible by 2.